# Resize terminal Emacs window to fit when resuming a Screen session from larger display in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, display, terminal, emacs, gnu-screen

Whenever I start a GNU screen session running GNU emacs (nw, so in terminal) on my desktop with a large monitor, then resume it on my laptop, emacs still thinks it's on a large monitor. This means as I move around the emacs window, a chunk of it goes outside the visible range; navigate to the bottom of my right buffer, and I no longer see the top of my left buffer.

Is there a way to reset the emacs window sizing for the terminal size I'm in after resuming a screen session? The terminal session itself is fine if I leave emacs, so just seems to be an emacs issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the session attached on the desktop and are sharing it with `screen -x`, the currently-displayed window does not automatically get refitted.

In any case, you can trigger a force-fit (i.e. update what the "terminal" will return as its size when queried, and, if that changed, send a SIGWINCH) with the "fit" command, by default bound to *e* F (default `^A F`, your escape key and bindings may vary).